# Negative exponential distance

Tags: general-topology, compactness, normed-spaces, connectedness

Let $X := \left\{(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb N}, a_k \in \mathbb C\right\}$. Let $d\left( (a_k)_{k \in \mathbb N}, (b_k)_{k \in \mathbb N} \right) := e^{-u}$ with $u$ the smallest integer $k$ such that $a_k \ne b_k$ be a distance on $X$. Is $(X, d)$ compact/complete/connected?

Here's my not very rigorous take : $X$ is not complete since it's not even a normed space (I don't think there exists a norm that induces $d$). It is not compact since $\left((1, \dots ), (2, \dots), (3, \dots), \dots\right)$ is a sequence of elements of $X$ that does not have a convergent subsequence. I can't find an argument for connectedness, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that $X$ is not compact, by exactly the example you mention.

On the other hand, $X$ is in fact complete.  Observe that if $d((a_k), (b_k)) < e^{-n}$, then $a_i = b_i$ for all $i \leq n$.  It follows that if $(\mathbf{a}_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} = ((a_{n,k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then for each $k$, the sequence $(a_{n,k})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is eventually constant (call its eventual value $b_k$).  One can then show that the sequence $(b_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ is the limit of $(\mathbf{a}_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$.

Finally, $X$ is not connected.  Indeed, for any $\mathbf{a} = (a_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$, the $\varepsilon$-ball $B$ centered at $\mathbf{a}$ is disjoint from the union of the $\varepsilon$-balls centered at at every $\mathbf{b} \not \in B$.  These are open, so it follows that $X$ is not connected.

Comment: Would you recommend a textbook for this type of things? Is this an elementary functional analysis problem? I'm following an introductory course in general topology but we haven't dealt much with function spaces.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ does not have to be a normed space in order to be complete. In fact, I think $X$ is complete indeed, you just need to work through the definitions.

In short: let $a^{(n)}$ be a Cauchy sequence. This means $a^{(n)}$ is very close to $a^{(m)}$ provided $n$ and $m$ are large enough. In other words, $a^{(n)}$ and $a^{(m)}$ agree up to an arbitrarily big rank $N$ provided that $n$ and $m$ are both large enough. Define $a_k = a^{(n)}_k = a^{(m)}_k$ for $k \leqslant N$. If you think about it, this is well defined and that $a^{(n)}$ converges to $a$.

I agree with your argument that shows that $X$ is not compact.

As for connectedness, what about this: Let $\nu : X \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ defined by $\nu(a) = \min \{n\in \mathbb{N}, a_n \neq 0\}$ (valuation). Check that $\nu$ is continuous. Conclude that $X$ is not connected.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. It made me double check the difference of a complete space and a Banach space..